# how to import all the points from a .pcd file into a 2d python array

Tags: python-3.x, point-cloud-library

How do you import all the 3d points from a file named edge_cloud.pcd and put them into an array? I want the array to be in the format

```
array=[[xvalue1,yvalue1,zvalue1],[xvalue2,yvalue2,zvalue2]]
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Tested with Python 3.7.3, `numpy` 1.16.2, and [`open3d`](https://pypi.org/project/open3d/) 0.7.0.0:

```
import numpy as np 
import open3d as o3d

pcd = o3d.io.read_point_cloud("C:\\Users\\Username\\Source\\pointcloud\\bunny.pcd")
out_arr = np.asarray(pcd.points)  
print("output array from input list : ", out_arr)
```

Output:

```
output array from input list :  
[[ 0.0054216  0.11349    0.040749 ]
 [-0.0017447  0.11425    0.041273 ]
 [-0.010661   0.11338    0.040916 ]
 ...
 [-0.064992   0.17802   -0.054645 ]
 [-0.069935   0.17983   -0.051988 ]
 [-0.07793    0.17516   -0.0444   ]]
```

Input PCD file:

https://github.com/PointCloudLibrary/pcl/blob/master/test/bunny.pcd

Comment: What if my points have 5 dimensions, like [x, y, z, intensity, time_stamp], open3d only provides format with 3,4,6 dimensions...

Comment: >>> import open3d as o3d
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/home/jhuai/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/open3d/__init__.py", line 9, in <module>
    from open3d.linux import *
  File "/home/jhuai/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/open3d/linux/__init__.py", line 7, in <module>
    globals().update(importlib.import_module('open3d.linux.open3d').__dict__)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.8/importlib/__init__.py", line 127
ImportError: /home/jhuai/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/open3d/linux/open3d.so: undefined symbol: _Py_ZeroStruct

Answer (score 1):

Tested with **python 3.8**, access pcd files using **pypcd**.

Install using  below command

```
    pip install pypcd
```

If this doesnt install, try below command

```
    python -m pip install --user git+https://github.com/DanielPollithy/pypcd.git
```

After the installation you can load pcd to numpy arrays using below code.

```
    from pypcd import pypcd
    pc = pypcd.PointCloud.from_path("demo.pcd")
    pc_data = pc.pc_data
    pc_array = np.array([pc_data["x"], pc_data["y"], pc_data["z"]], dtype=np.float32)
```

https://github.com/dimatura/pypcd

Comment: >>> from pypcd import pypcd
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/home/jhuai/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pypcd/pypcd.py", line 15, in <module>
    import cStringIO as sio
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'cStringIO'